# Alternative to Content-Disposition in HTTP Header (c#)

Tags: c#, http-headers, httpresponse, content-disposition

Is there an **alternative** for Content-Disposition with "attachment; filename=..."?

I'm sending a streamed on the fly exe file and wish the browser to open the "save as" or "run" when I begin sending.

I'm using the C# HttpResponseHeader and wish to use its members or the HttpWorkerRequest members.

Thanks, Moshe

Comment: What's wrong with the Content-Disposition header?

Comment: Agreed.  Content-Disposition is the correct way to get the browser to prompt the user to save the file.  Use HttpResponse.AppendHeader() to add the header value, ie:  Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=...")

Comment: Note: If you omit the content-type header, some browsers (e.g. Opera) will give the file the wrong filename extension, regardless of what you chose for it.

Comment: "attachment; filename=" Didnt work?. Then try Response.AddHeader("content-type", "application/octet-stream"). This will force the "Save As/Open With" dialog box to show up.

Comment: Content-disposition has some security issues and is not part of HTTP 1.1

Comment: @RemyLebeau put that as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.
Thanks to all the other commenters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Content-Disposition` is the correct way to get the browser to prompt the user to save the file. Use `HttpResponse.AppendHeader()` to add the header value, eg:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "...") 
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=...")
```